# Magento layout not working in custom theme

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layout, custom, toplinks

I don't know if this question has answered before. I am creating a custom theme in magento 2.1. My parent theme is magento/blank.

**I have copied layout and template files from `module-theme\view\frontend` and pasted in `app/design/frontend/vendor/themename/Magento_Theme/`**

My problem is that I lost the top links with welcome message after copying and pasting the layout folder. If i rename `app/design/frontend/vendor/themename/Magento_Theme/layout` to any random name top links appears.

Can any one help me to sort it out? Thank you.

Comment: Copy only file-names not content. And copy only required files which need to edit. You only need to add updated code in these files. try this

Comment: I need exact same layout in as in magento blank. Can I use the same codes in module-theme\view\frontend\layout\default.xml?

Comment: Yes, you can use

Comment: I have removed the unwanted files. Now my custom theme layout folder have only default.xml and default_head_blocks.xml only. Still it is not working. But if I rename custom theme layout folder to something else, it is working.

Comment: clear the content of both files and check site

Comment: Then it works. But now it is taking from the core files, right? Which I shouldn't be changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60623/discussion-between-jai-and-hakkim).

Comment: You add updated code in default.xml file.  Only which you want to edit not all. ie if you to remove any element then you can mention liek this <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are few thing to do:

- Copy only file-names from parent theme. And copy only required files which need to edit. You only need to add updated code in these files.
- You add updated code in default.xml file. Only which you want to edit not all. ie if you to remove any element then you can mention like this `<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>` inside body tag